# How do I use this code from the Flutter Engish_Words package?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to learn Flutter (As someone without a lot of programming background) and in a tutorial have just learned how to import the English Words package.

I have tried to use the example code as shown at: https://pub.dev/packages/english_words.

The error I receive is:  This expression has a type of void so its value cannot be used. It is the line: `nouns.take(50).forEach(print);` that gives the error.

This is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:english_words/english_words.dart';

void main() {
  home: Scaffold(
    body: SafeArea(
      child: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: Text(
              nouns.take(50).forEach(print);
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );

  }
```

Thanks for any clues.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because `nouns` returns a `List<String>` and `foreach` is a `void` method, which returns nothing. But your `Text` requires a String. If you want to display all nouns make use of  [ListView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html). Below is a small example.

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<String> words = nouns.take(50).toList();

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => Text(words[index]),
          itemCount: words.length,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Really appreciate your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Everything in flutter is a Widget as well as **Text**, used as a child of Container widget.

> The error I receive is: This expression has a type of void so its value cannot be used. It is the line: nouns.take(50).forEach(print); that gives the error.

the line: `nouns.take(50).forEach(print)`, actually return a list of 50 most used nouns and printing them. In Dart & Flutter `print` is a function that return void. **void** means nothing. so the line `nouns.take(50).forEach(print)` actually returns nothing but **Text Widget** requires `String` in order to display on screen.

Comment: Thanks for the tip..value your time in posting this. Thank you!